# function template implicit instatiation with explicit template argument vs deduced template arguments

Tags: templates

[cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/421a79c1)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
int is_pointer_f(T p) { return 1; }

template <typename T>
int is_pointer_f(T* p) { return 2; }

template <typename T>
int is_pointer_f(const T* p) { return 3; }

int main()
{
    const int* a = 0;
    std::cout<< is_pointer_f< decltype(a) >(a) <<"\n";
    std::cout<< is_pointer_f(a)                <<"\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This prints 1 and 3.

The 3 is as expected and explained here: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) (search for `void f(const T*);` for an example identical to this one) but for the first call I would expect the same overload to be used.

What happens for explicit template arguments in function templates?

Also these rules seem to not apply for class template specializations, where the expected specialization is selected. [cppinsight](https://cppinsights.io/s/8a2c44c5) with is_pointer "standard" implementation.

This seems like a basic question but I wasn't able to find an answer or deduce one from other questions.